# How to read recognizing class and fields from file input?

Tags: java, arrays, oop, bufferedreader, filereader

I have a file like the following:

```
7
CAT   Tabby   Jane   F   2   7.0   true   false
DOG   Sam    Jeff   M   7   32.1   true
CAT  Elsie   Kate   F   9   9.8   true   true
DOG  Spot    Dick   M   6   63.4   false
BIRD  Tweety  Dick   M   3   0.06   false
BIRD  Opus   Berkeley   M   31   10.3   true
DOG  Spot    John   M   3   42.6   true
```

First column of my file represent classes and the following columns represent variable/field values of the respective classes.I want to read the lines in certain way so that my reader recognizes that first column is class, second is name variable,third is owner variable fourth is sex of the name(pet) and so forth.
The following are the variables(just in case you need strong idea):

```
    protected String name;
    protected String owner;
    protected String sex = "F";
    protected int age = 3;
    protected double weight = 5.0;
    protected boolean spayedNeutered;  
    private boolean declawed;(which is a subclass filed)
```

So when I'm reading the file input the following way:

```
public void readData()  throws Exception{
    BufferedReader filename = new BufferedReader(new   FileReader("pets.txt"));
    String str;

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
   while((str = filename.readLine()) != null){
            String[] temp = str.split("\\s+",2);
            list.add(temp[1]);
        }

    pets = list.toArray(new String[6]);

    for (String x: pets) {
        System.out.println(x);
    }

    }
```

This will just printing plain data as it is from file.I have no idea how to tell the reader to recognize that each specific columns represent class and respective(in order) variable values.After I recognize the fields and class, I will put them in an array like Pet [] pets(Pet is my parent/super class).Then I will apply customized toString methods to print the object arrays in certain way like the following:

```
> java AnimalHospital pets.data
Tabby owned by Jane: Small Cat, F, Age 2, 7.0 lbs. (not declawed)
Sam owned by Jeff: Medium Dog, M, Age 7, 32.1 lbs.
Elsie owned by Kate: Medium Cat, F, Age 9, 9.8 lbs.
Spot owned by Dick: Large Dog, M, Age 6, 63.4 lbs. (not spayed/neutered)
Tweety owned by Dick: Small Bird, M, Age 3, 0.06 lbs. (not clipped)
Opus owned by Berkeley: Large Bird, M, Age 31, 10.3 lbs.
Spot owned by John: Medium Dog, M, Age 3, 42.6 lbs.
```

I hope my question has more than enough information to clarify my core question.

Comment: You need to use a construct like `Class.forName()`. This technique is called reflection.

Comment: @Evangey It says reflection is a powerful tool and recommended to use only by the advanced users who know basic functionality.Can you suggest any other technique that a beginner like me can use?I really want to learn, as opposed to just using an advanced API class that will do the trick.

Comment: Re reflection - indeed, reflection is powerful, although there is nothing wrong in using powerful tools, and no way of learning them without trying...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that using BufferedReader.BufferedReader doesn't have that functionality.You have to parse it.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your question, you have to basically do a mapping of class-name and the value. You can use Map for this.

Since you know that first column is class of pet, second is name, third is sex etc, so after splitting the whole line on basis of " ", you can use Map m such that:

```
m.put("class",temp[0]);
m.put("name",temp[1]);
```

and so on...

And return type will be Map.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid reflection, and assuming you know all your classes beforehand and you use java8, you could write a switch statement like this:

```
Animal animal;
switch (tmp[0]) {
    case "CAT":
        animal = new Cat();
        break;
    case "DOG":
        animal = new Dog();
        break;
// etc etc
    default:
        throw new RuntimeException("Unknown animal:" + tmp[0]);
}
```